# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^n a_n \le n a_{n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider an increasing sequence $a_n$

Prove that $$a_1+a_2+a_3+.....+a_n \le na_{n+1}$$

This is just a part of a question I am trying to solve. If I can prove the above part, I can prove the original problem.

The original problem is: $$b_n=\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+.....+a_n}{n}$$
where $a_n$ is an increasing sequence and I need to prove $b_n$ is an increasing sequence.

Comment: you cannot use the same letter $n$ in those two ways; if you wish, just switch to $N$

Answer (score 1):

Write the right part in sigma notation and you will see what happens.

$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \le \sum_{i=1}^n a_{n+1}$ because every single term in the left side is less or equal to the right side.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \le \sum_{i=1}^n a_{n+1}$;
$\sum_{i=1}^n a_{n+1}=na_{n+1}$
But how do I prove it?
It is going to be under assumption that:
Since $a_1\le a_2\le...\le a_n\le a_{n+1}$, adding all the term, $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{n+1}=a_1+a_2+...+a_n+a_{n+1}=na_{n+1}$,which is sort of approximation, right?

Comment: Read carefully what the formula represents: $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{n+1}=a_{n+1}+a_{n+1}+...+a_{n+1}=na_{n+1}$. Combined with the way you wrote the question, it seems you are a bit confused with the dummy variable in the sigma notation, it would be helpful to review that.

Comment: I edited my question so that it exactly looks like original one. However, I don't understand why it is $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{n+1} = a_{n+1}+a_{n+1}+...+a_{n+1}$

Comment: Never mind. I just figured it out. Thanks.